# How do I code-sign the executable launcher that is created when bundling a JavaFX application?

Tags: java, windows, ant, javafx, code-signing

So after much pain I'm coming to the completion of my project and now I need to know how to code sign the executable. No, not the .jar, I know how to do that. What I need is to be able to code-sign the .exe file that launches the .jar for our users, so that they don't see the "Do you want to allow the following program from an unknown publisher" warning message.

I know how to customize the process with an INNO script and I can use that to code-sign the installer, and I know how to include different icon files that will be used for the executables and shortcuts, and I know how to code-sign the jar through the ANT script, but this, this eludes me entirely.

So, does anyone know how I can go about code-signing the .exe that launches the jar when bundling a self-contained JavaFX application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay so I found it. This is pretty painful because there are (if I'm using this term in the correct context) "race conditions" here in that if the code signing doesn't finish before you start running the process again, it fails because it can't do anything with the .exe because it's being used by another process.

Turns out as long as your IDE is running in Admin (for Windows anyway) there's no need to elevate your script either.

Anyay, my problem was that the file was being set as Read-Only. VERY annoying but fortunately VBScript allows for you to change a files attributes so it was just a matter of doing that before trying to code-sign it :

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
<package>
    <job id="CodeSign">
    <script language = "VBScript">
        <![CDATA[    
            'Set File as Normal. . .

            Dim objFSO, objFile
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("<Relative Path>\<File.exe>")
            objFile.Attributes = 0

            Dim Shell
            Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            Shell.Run "<Code Sign> ""<Relative Path>\<File.exe>""", 1, True
            Set Shell = Nothing
            Set objFSO = Nothing
            Set objFile = Nothing
        ]]>
    </script>
    </job>
</package>
```

So now, finally, at LONG LAST we have a complete and viable answer to this, evidently very esoteric question that no one but myself has dealt with (or is a very closely guarded secret, I'm not sure which) : How do you code-sign the executable created by a JavaFX bundle before it gets stored?

- Create a WSF file with either JavaScript or VBScript (your
  preference)
- Add the directory in which the file is being stored to the Class Path (for NetBeans you go to Tools -> Options -> Java Tab, select Add Directory next to Class Path, browse to the directory, and add it).
- In your WSF file, in the Script section, get the file object and set its attributes to normal (0).
- Then Shell.Run your preferred method of code signing applications. 1 is for showing the Code Sign window, True is to make the VBScript wait until it's finished to hopefully avoid a race condition.

The .exe will ALWAYS be stored one directory up from the WSF script file so the relative path is always going to be `<FILENAME>\<FILENAME.exe>`.

I really, REALLY hope this saves someone a LOT of grief some day...

Comment: Thank you! This saved me lots of time. I just needed a way to change the file attribute to read-only and your code worked great!

Comment: As for the signing I decided to let innosetup reprocessing take care of that. Perhaps that will fix the race condition that you talked about. Just add this line to beginning of your inno setup script: #expr Exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x64\signtool.exe", "sign /n Concord /tr http://tsa.starfieldtech.com " + AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "MyFolder\MyFile.exe")

Comment: I'm glad this helped someone. I looked in my email and was like "Stack exchange? What?"

Comment: Surprised it doesn't have more upvotes. Anybody who tries to use Javafx ant to build and sign bundle installers will surely face this problem.

Comment: @SaeidNourian I tried your suggestion adding #expr directive ino innosetup script. Unfortunately I've a "SignTool Error: Access is denied." during the [ISPP] Preprocessing. The .exe directory is right but maybe the processing is done too early. Some ideas? Thanks

Comment: @drenda Sounds like your exe file is a read-only file. In order for this to work you need to change the permission of this file to allow it to have "write" permission.

Comment: @SaeidNourian I'm using classical ant script for JavaFx desktop app with a customized InnoSetup script to change icons and other small things. I can't change manually the permission of the file because is ant script and innosetup that works on it directly. Thanks

Comment: @drenda I posted the solution as a new answer below

Comment: Ok, now it's much more clear :-) Thanks, solved with your suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

Add the following as first line of package/windows/MyProject.iss file:

```
#expr Exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x64\signtool.exe", "sign /n CompanyName /tr tsa.starfieldtech.com " + AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "MyProject\MyProject.exe")
```

To ensure that exe file is writable add package/windows/MyProject-post-image.wsf:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
<package>
    <job id="CodeSign">
    <script language = "VBScript">
        <![CDATA[    
            'Set File as Normal. . .

            Dim objFSO, objFile
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("MyProject\MyProject.exe")
            objFile.Attributes = 0

        ]]>
    </script>
    </job>
</package>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what goes in the MyProject.iss file. I currently don't have such a file and simply let javapackager put everything together for me. I create the .iss file with the single line that you've suggested and received an error that said it needed a [Setup] section with AppName, AppVerName and DefaultDirName. Wasn't sure what to do, but when I put these in, nothing got signed and the final .exe file wasn't created properly. How do I do this?

Comment: Yes your .iss file shouldn't be empty. When you use javapackager it will create a default .iss for you and in the output it will tell you where this .iss file is saved. Go to that folder and copy the .iss somewhere else. Then add the above line for signing exe to the beginning of the .iss file.

Comment: Thank you. I just put this file with iss. before code signing a script is executed in time. Good knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that as of Inno Setup 5.5.9 (2016-04-06) there is Flag 'sign' for the Files section that can be used to sign the application exe. You still need to add the .wsf file to package/windows folder as indicated in other answers.

http://www.jrsoftware.org/files/is5-whatsnew.htm